# (Android+Room+Kotlin) Inserted float value is modified (19.6 becomes 19.6000003814697)

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, retrofit

I have coded a service that gets a float value through Retrofit2 from a remote server.

The value that comes from the server is going into a var declared as :

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "tax")
var tax: Float?
```

After getting the value from the server, the value of the variable is written to the log and seems ok ("19.6" is well written to the debug output).

When checking the data in the table, with SqlLiteDatabaseBrowser 3.10.1, the value that has been written in the table is "19.6000003814697"

Also "2.1" becomes "2.09999990463257"

And "0.9" becomes "0.899999976158142"

Would you know what is happening ?

Thanks

Comment: use `BigDecimal` ... `Float` and `Double` are floating point representations and therefore inaccurate.

Comment: Ok I have tried but now I must use a Converter to convert Float to BigDecimal...

Comment: using `Long` and shifting the comma by a few digits instead of assuming a `Float`  value might be less prone to such inaccuracies.

Comment: Yes that is what I was going to to. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now storing float values from the server as String in the SQL Lite database through Room. Thank you for the clue, Martin Zeitler.

Comment: `Long` can also be used - and this won't prevent Sqlite domain aggregate functions, hence it is still some kind of numeric value. sadly Sqlite does not support `BigDecimal`, which would make numeric value storage and calculation easier.

Comment: Ok yes I would consider it as an alternative if needed.